# Unknown column issue with mysql alias subquery and MATCH

Tags: mysql

I and trying to run a query that searches the same thing within 3 tables using MATCH and Subqueries Alias.

Where is the query

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    (SELECT TypeName FROM table2 WHERE id = table.id) AS type
FROM table 
WHERE 
    MATCH (name, type) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2')
```

Any Ideas how to solve it?

Comment: No idea what you are asking. Show some sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

My two MSQL tables are like this:

```
table
| id | name       | type |
|  1 | John Smith |   1  |
|  2 | Mark Taylor |   1  |

table2
| id | TypeName       | description |
|  1 | Student        | bla bla bla |
```

so if I search for keyword1 and keyword2 (john student) The results should be both lines from Table table.